# What is MAP in web computer science?

Tags: dictionary

I want to ask a question about the 'MAP' in Web technology. What is the meaning of the 'MAP', I only know this is related to the web 2.0 , but don't have any idea, can anyone help me or give me some reference to me? Thank you.

// ---------- Update ----------

thank you very much.

I found the answer is the MAP = Mail Admin Page

Comment: Can you give more context? Where have you seen it used?

Comment: You mean something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web ?

Comment: @all, this is one of the topic of my assignment, but I only have to name, I have to find some related information. Thank you.

Comment: next time, it should be tagged "homework"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(disambiguation)) gives many possible meanings for the word (by itself or an acronym), but only a few are computer related and none is really specific to web 2.0 -- it may indicate a specific higher-order function very popular in functional language, an "associative array", or the file format for Quake maps (or, also, the file format for a certain kind of debugging symbols).

What context have you met the word in?  It has to be pretty specific if wikipedia doesn't have it in its disambiguation page...!-)